# Use last_value in BigQuery with struct data

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to pull transactions by last non-direct channel for GA4 in BigQuery and want to calculate the last source/medium/campaign using last_value. However, this is not working if source/medium/campagin/gclid are merged together in a struct

It works only if I concatenate them in a string. However I'd like to avoid using this as any delimiter I use to create the string and separate the elements could potentially be part of a campaign name

The data below is a script I'm using on GA4 BQ data but the concept could apply to any other dataset

```
with events as (
  select
    event_name,
    user_pseudo_id,
    (select as struct 
      (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'source') as source,
      (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'medium') as medium,
      (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'campaign') as campaign,
      (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'gclid') as gclid
    ) as traffic_source,
    event_timestamp,
    (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'transaction_id') as transaction_id
  from `xxx.analytics_12345.events_20230618`
  where
    (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'source') IS NOT NULL OR
    event_name = 'purchase'
  order by event_timestamp)

select
  transaction_id,
  last_value(traffic_source ignore nulls) 
    over(partition by user_pseudo_id
      order by event_timestamp range between 2592000000 preceding and current row -- 30 day lookback
    ) as last_source
from events
where transaction_id is not null
```

The table I'm trying to obtain will have transaction_id and relative last non-direct source, medium, channel (where present) and gclid (where present)

Thank you